# Not adding object key/value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to add a key/value pair to my object in Javascript.

I have tried a variety of methods but nothing seems to work.

```
user.find({ email: email }, async function (err, foundTenants) {
        console.log(foundTenants[0].rooms)
        let allrooms = foundTenants[0].rooms

        for (let i = 0; i < allrooms.length; i++) {
            allrooms[i].allPaid = true;
            console.log('allroomssss', allrooms[i])
```

The allpaid key does not get added in the object.

Is there any way to fix this?

value of foundTenants[0].rooms

```
 [
[server]   {
[server]     _id: 6098086ef9337b3d111bd419,
[server]     key: '9RHMEg',
[server]     rent: 500,
[server]     address: '23 fake street'
[server]   },
[server]   {
[server]     _id: 60984e7699790948ef829251,
[server]     key: '6bvCis',
[server]     rent: 400,
[server]     address: 'jumpman'
[server]   }
[server] ]
```

Comment: Please share the value of the "foundTenants"

Comment: Question, how is this find method working, show us your entire code.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing how your find method is working and wondering why you are only working with the first `foundTenants` and not even checking if the first item in the array exists.

```
user.find({ email: email }, async (err, foundTenants) => {
    const allrooms = foundTenants[0].rooms.map(room => {
        return {
            ...room,
            allPaid: true,
        }
    });
}
```

use `.map` when you want to modify items in arrays. its an array containing objects, you can then destructure it with `...item` to return all of its current info and tack on any additional.